# OpenXML reading wrong cell value if integer

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am reading the cell values using this code;

```
            var cell = row.Elements<Cell>().FirstOrDefault();
            var stringId = Convert.ToInt32(cell.InnerText);

            var cellValue = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable
                .Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(stringId).InnerText;
```

I am reading first cells of rows and get the value. My excel is like this.

```
     A    B
 1   x    name1
 2   y    name2
 3   1    name3
```

So when the row is 3, the `stringId` value is set as 1 and the `cellValue` is set as "`x`", but it should be 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the `DataType` of the cell as the "1" is stored as an actual number, not a string in the shared strings table.

```
var cell = row.Elements<Cell>().FirstOrDefault();
string cellValue = null;

if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
{
    //it's a shared string so use the cell inner text as the index into the 
    //shared strings table
    var stringId = Convert.ToInt32(cell.InnerText);
    cellValue = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable
        .Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(stringId).InnerText;
}
else
{
    //it's NOT a shared string, use the value directly
    cellValue = cell.InnerText;
}
```

There are a couple of things to note:
1) The default type if one is not provided is Number
2) There are other types that are not handled by the code above. Dates are particularly awkward.